# How to do click item with pagination?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pagination

Use react.js. Catching hard to understanding error. My component without pagination work well - show you all items and you can see the item by click. Pagination work fine too, but i cant click on item in item list. Actualy i can click, but displaying only first page items. If you click on item from 2-nd(3,4...n) page you get item from 1-st page.

[Open CodePen with my code](https://codepen.io/d2207/pen/oNxvzLo)

```
export function ListOfItems() {
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [postsPerPage] = useState(10);
    const users = useSelector(state => state);
    

    const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
    const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
    const currentPosts = users.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
    const paginate = pageNumber => setCurrentPage(pageNumber);

    let items = currentPosts.map(function (value, index) {
        return (
            <form key={index}>
                <div className="input-group">
                    <div className="input-group-prepend">
                        <Link className="input-group-text" to={`${url}/${index}`}>
                            {value.name}
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <div>{items}</div>
            <Pagination postsPerPage={postsPerPage} totalUsers={users.length} paginate={paginate}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that codepen doesn't run. But my guess would be to look at the Pagination component.

Comment: @Yann Pagination component are in codepen. You can look.

Comment: May been u right, pagination component return just `<button>`,  May replace `<button>` by `<a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently I've built something like you.
There is a more clean way to do it.
I recommend you to separate your logic in custom hooks.
For example, you can create custom hook:

```
export const usePagination = (posts, defaultPage = 1, amountPerPage = 10) => {
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(defaultPage);
  const [postsPerPage] = useState(amountPerPage);
  const indexOfLastPost = currentPage * postsPerPage;
  const indexOfFirstPost = indexOfLastPost - postsPerPage;
  let currentPosts = [];
  let amountOfPages = 0;
  if (Array.isArray(posts)) {
    currentPosts = posts.slice(indexOfFirstPost, indexOfLastPost);
    amountOfPages = Math.ceil(posts.length / postsPerPage);
  }
  return {
    setCurrentPage,
    amountOfPages,
    currentPosts,
  };
};
```

And use it in any component you need. For example:

```
const { setCurrentPage, currentPosts, amountOfPages } = usePagination(yourArrayOfData);
```

And for example you can use it that way(I was using Material UI Pagination component):

```
    <Pagination
      count={amountOfPages}
      onChange={(event, page) => setCurrentPage(page)}
    />
```

And use currentPosts for actually displaying your data.
I know, that it's not direct answer to your question, but recently I have written something like you and it worked perfectly. So I hope that my solution will help you.

Comment: yeah, its not answer for my question, but its mach better! Thx u. get cycling at page just freezes page. I think i do `usePagination` alright but i miss something please watch the pen  [link](https://codepen.io/d2207/pen/OJNLxMV?editors=1010)